# App Crashes when Implementing Bottom navigation with nav controller

Tags: java, android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-navhostfragment

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
```

Whenever I run this code the app crashes and I have linked all the ids perfectly
What should I do?

I just wanted a dfunctioning bottom navigation bar and the app crashes

Comment: Attach stacktrace

Comment: Attach the error stacktrace also provide the XML file which have the NavHost Widget